# how to run python script from php on xamp?

Tags: php, python-2.7

Following is the php code that I was using. I am trying to run this script(residing in the same directory as the php file is in) and want to display the output of the script on webpage. Script is working fine through command prompt, but not working thru php script.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>py script</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>hey there!</h1>
<?
$pyscript = 'C:\\xampp_new\\htdocs\\projectx\\USR.py';
$python = 'C:\\Python27\\python.exe';
exec("$python $pyscript ", $output, $return );
echo $return;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the output ? and what error do you encounter ?

Comment: its showing only the header " hey there!"  on  browser . $return value is not displayed on browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>py script</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>hey there!</h1>
<?
$pyscript = 'C:/xampp_new/htdocs/projectx/USR.py';
$python = 'C:/Python27/python.exe';
$command=escapeshellcmd('C:/xampp_new/htdocs/projects/USR.py');
$output=shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several options why your `exec` call won't work:

1. Are you running om [safe_mode](http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php) ? `exec` is disabled in safe mode
2. Your std output is at `$output` which is more interesting than the return value
3. if your python script working ? try in PHP: `exec("$python $pyscript >test.txt");` and see if your text file has anything in it

Comment: i'm using xampp on windows.. thats why 3rd step is not working for me.... .can you elaborate 2nd point.